# get all values of clicked input field row

Tags: html, jquery

good morning,

maybe a easy question for you but a big step for me ;)
I have this simple and table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething()" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething()" value="22"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething()" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething()" value="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething()" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething()" value="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>




function doSomething() {
    //code
}
```

As you can see I have 3 rows which the same structure.
If you click on any input field the function doSomething will call.

Now my question (example):
If I click on the input field with the value 44 I would like to get all values of this row (row 2).

The output should be:

- 33
- 44

Can you explain me please how I can realize this?
Thank you very much !!

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: Assuming you know jquery, the solution is to get the closest td of the clicked text box and get reference of the td's siblings. You can select/traverse the text boxes from that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var doSomething;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    doSomething = function(el) {
    const tdInputChild = $(el).parent().parent().find('input');
    
    console.log('myFieldA',$(tdInputChild[0]).val());
    console.log('myFieldB',$(tdInputChild[1]).val());
  //  For Dynamic you can use loop or map to get val.
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="22"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" onclick="doSomething(this)" value="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I recommend always using `.closest("tr")` then it doesn't matter if you wrap the inputs/buttons in another div (for whatever reason).

Comment: `$("#parent` is a little confusing - what's "#parent"?   Did you mean `parent.find(":input")`?

Comment: #parent here is the element you got it from `$(this).parent().parent();`

yes using `.closest("tr")` is much easier and shorter than ` $(this).parent().parent();  `

Comment: Thank you ! I tried this to get the value of myFieldB:
`var tr =  $(this).closest("tr"); $(tr + ' . myFieldB').val();` but I get an error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] .myFieldB`

Comment: Try this : ` $(this).closest("tr").find('input');`

this will return a array.

Comment: @Ghost108 Check my answer i have updated a demo code. also if it help yours please dont forget to upvote it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get all the inputs for a row, you can add the click event to the row itself.

```
$("tr").click...
```

then access the inputs with `$(this).find(".myFieldA")` (etc)

```js
$("table tr").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find(".myFieldA").val(), $(this).find(".myFieldB").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In some cases there may be a `td` you don't want to have a click event on, so it's easier to add the click event to the cells you do want or to all the cells excluding the ones you don't want:

```
$("td.click").click...
$("td:not(.noclick)").click...
```

with the event on the `td` (or on the `input` if you prefer) you can access the `tr` with

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

```js
$("table tr td:not(.noclick)").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    console.log(row.find(".myFieldA").val(), row.find(".myFieldB").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't know how many inputs there are and just want an array of values, you can use `.map`

```
var values = row.find(":input").map((i,e)=> $(e).val()).toArray();
```

where `row` is the `tr` from previous and `.toArray()` converts to a "clean" array (useful with `console.log`)

```js
$("table tr td:not(.noclick)").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var values = row.find(":input").map((i,e)=> $(e).val()).toArray();
    console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This can then be extended to give you an array of objects with key/value

```
    var values = row.find(":input").map((i,e)=> {
      return { 
        key : e.className, 
        value : $(e).val()
      }
    }).toArray();
```

```js
$("table tr td:not(.noclick)").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var values = row.find(":input").map((i,e)=> {
      return { 
        key : e.className, 
        value : $(e).val()
      }
    }).toArray();
    console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you prefer an object (probably the most useful) rather than a key/value array:

```
    var values = {};
    row.find(":input").each((i,e) => 
      values[e.className] = $(e).val()
    );
```

```js
$("table tr td:not(.noclick)").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var values = {};
    row.find(":input").each((i,e) => 
      values[e.className] = $(e).val()
    );
    console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
    <td class="noclick">click here doesn't give values</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple without adding jQuery.

Add a click event listener on each of your table rows (your `tr`s), then loop through the children (this will be your `td` elements).

Finally, get the value of each child of your `td`, then output it:

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
let results = document.getElementById('results');

rows.forEach((row) => {

  row.addEventListener('click', getValues);

});

function getValues() {

  let currentRow = event.currentTarget;
  let output = [];
  
  // get the children (your td elements) of the currently clicked row
  for (let i = 0; i < currentRow.children.length; i++) {
    //get the value of the child input element
    output.push(currentRow.children[i].firstChild.value);
  }

  results.innerText= output;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the click event is bubbling up, you can set a listener on the row instead on each input.

```js
$('table tr').click(doSomething);

function doSomething() {
    let vals = [];
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        vals.push(this.value);
    });
    console.log(vals.join());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA"value="11"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="22"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="33"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="44"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldA" value="55"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="myFieldB" value="66"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```